# mvc anyway to have hash in the title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there anyway to have a title like how twitter used to, eg siteurl.com/#/anything

/@/ works but /#/ does nothing

```
<add url="@/{username}" controller="Users" action="ProfilePage">
<constraints>
  <add key="username" value="[\w\-%]+?" />
</constraints>
<defaults>
  <add key="page" value="0" />
</defaults>
```

this works but replace the @ with a # and it does nothing, ive deleted all other routes to make sure there's no conflict

Answer (score 0):

The hash, in the way Twitter uses it, is for JavaScript routing. The actual page URL is just `siteurl.com`, with an anchor of `/anything`. The anchor is not truly part of the URL, it's a reference to a document location. In the case of JS frameworks which support routing, it's used to determine what view fragment should be loaded on the page dynamically.